# How do you cast a health or ammo pack onto yourself in BF4?

Tags: battlefield-4

When I watch some videos of people playing the Assault or Supply classes in BF4, sometimes they will cast a health or ammo pack such that it appears right in front of their view for their own use immediately.  For example, Matimio often does this in his vids.

How do you do this?  When I try to use these packs, it always "throws" the pack forward, which is normally what I would expect when giving packs to other people.  This isn't ideal because I have to run forward to pick it up, which often means going out of cover when I'm trying to heal or reload.

I'm on the PC version of BF4.

Comment: They might be dropping it the same way you would a weapon. In BF3 I think the key was 'G'.

Comment: Can't you just try throwing it on the floor by aiming at your feet or by throwing it at a wall (the wall you are behind cover)? That's what I use to do in BF3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After viewing some of the vids I was seeing more carefully, I realized that the people were using health and ammo crates instead of the ammo packs that are meant to be thrown at other people.  It doesn't look like there is a good way to self-cast an ammo pack.

Comment: There are some uses where the packs come in handy. In particular after the last big Patch, you do not heal from crates while suppressed but packs still work. And even further, you can deploy a pack and move while healing, while the crate is binding you to its possition. And even further, packs and crates stack. So if you're score-farming on Locker or so and every medic revives with 20hp instantly (so you cant get many revive points) you may expand your healing score potential by taking both with you, stack and crates.

Comment: Especially when you play combat medic (drop several kits/crates at once, very fast revive reload) you can just run arount spaming medkits and see the score raising like donald ducks money.

Answer (score 4):

bobfet1 already said it:

> It doesn't look like there is a good way to self-cast an ammo pack.

You can adjust the range your soldier throws the package. If you look closer to the ground, you throw it in front of your own legs. This is how you can supply yourself without moving. Keep in mind that you don't have to stand exactly on your supply, it has a small range.
Others, by the way, can also get supplied by this, so if you want to supply only yourself, keep in mind you need a little distance to your mates.

Comment: This is the best way.  If you don't have the crate unlocked already, definitely just look down and it'll throw.  It can be done very quickly.

Answer (score -5):

Hold down your button or push it fast a few times

Comment: Could you expand on this a little? Which button?